# Building Forums with Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, user-access, forum

I'm trying to build some sort of a discussion boards by using custom post types and the built in comments.

The structure is as following: 
An archive page to list all the pages of the Forum type, so each page is a "forum"
Each "forum" has a title , a small description and then some threaded comments as threads with replies

I think I'm at the right direction here, but I have a couple of question and maybe some one could assist me with them:

1. Is it possible to have user to be associated with specific pages? 
   **Example:** I'd like user A, B, C to be able to view "Forum" (page) 1;
   user D, E, F -> "Forum" (page) 2;
   etc.
2. Is it possible to have users to be redirected on sign up to their profile page, but disable all other menus in the admin area for them?
3. Is it possible to allow some users to be able to moderate comments only but not to see the other options on the site?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you might be better suited to [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/)?

Comment: Well I started with bbPress. Then I realized bbPress doesn't have these capabilities either, it doesn't have threaded posts and plugins for ver.2.0 are no where to be found. I thought that it might be best for me to build this type of thing myself and I will be probably more lucky to find some regular WP plugins to complement this setup.

Comment: Props for having a go with WordPress ;) But I dare say you might be better suited to running a dedicate forum app - what are your motives for using WP?

Comment: You might be right in general, I wouldn't think of using wordpress probably in any other case. But looking at the design of this "forums" and the requirements I've decided that it might be best to use WP. This website is built on WP and already has some custom post type, plus the requirements are very very basic. Any other "true forum" software like phpBB or vBulletin would be a huge overkill. What is needed is a simple and discrete place for specific users to post some questions and for others to answer them.

Comment: These "boards" will not be public. The users are small groups of professionals seeking support from other professionals in that specific field.  The users are super non-techies. We are talking about plumbers, electricians, etc. They would only want to get in there, login, ask a question and get an answer. This is also why I need to keep users separated - plumbers don't need to see the electricians questions and vise versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [User Access Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-access-manager/) for point 1).

For stripping back the menus & controlling access, check out the [User Role Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/). You can strip user capabilities down to the bare essentials, and a lot of the items in the menu will disappear for them. For example, removing all `*_themes` privileges will hide the Appearance item.

You may find you can't quite hide all the menus you want, so you can hook into `admin_menu` and conditionally use `remove_menu_page` and `remove_submenu_page` depending on `current_user_can( 'role_name_or_capability' )`.

For the redirect, check out `wp-login.php` - there should be a decent hook or filter in there for you to use and change where the user gets redirected; either after logging in or registering.

Comment: User Access Manager is exactly what I wanted. Great plugin, thank you. Still struggling with the other two, but I feel I'm really getting there. :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to come back if you get stuck ;)